# nested json to pandas very slow

Tags: python, json, pandas, performance

I am trying to convert a 321 `MB` nested json file to a pandas `Dataframe` and it is taking me a **very very** long time, i am sure that there is a faster way to do this, this is my code:

this is how the data looks like:

```
js_dict["data"][0:5]
d = [{'datetime': '2013-01-01T00:00:00+02:00', 'channels': [
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Rain', 'alias': None, 'value': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 2, 'name': 'WSmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 7.7, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 3, 'name': 'WDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 52.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 4, 'name': 'WS', 'alias': None, 'value': 5.2, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 5, 'name': 'WD', 'alias': None, 'value': 56.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 6, 'name': 'STDwd', 'alias': None, 'value': 11.9, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 7, 'name': 'RH', 'alias': None, 'value': 55.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 8, 'name': 'TD', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 10, 'name': 'TDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.6, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 11, 'name': 'TDmin', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 13, 'name': 'WS1mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 6.2, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 14, 'name': 'Ws10mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 5.3, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
{'id': 15, 'name': 'Time', 'alias': None, 'value': 2351.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None}]},
 {'datetime': '2013-01-01T00:10:00+02:00', 'channels': [
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'Rain', 'alias': None, 'value': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'WSmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 9.7, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'WDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 42.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'WS', 'alias': None, 'value': 6.3, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 5, 'name': 'WD', 'alias': None, 'value': 55.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 6, 'name': 'STDwd', 'alias': None, 'value': 12.6, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 7, 'name': 'RH', 'alias': None, 'value': 54.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 8, 'name': 'TD', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 10, 'name': 'TDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 11, 'name': 'TDmin', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 13, 'name': 'WS1mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 7.7, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 14, 'name': 'Ws10mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 6.3, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 15, 'name': 'Time', 'alias': None, 'value': 10.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None}]},
 {'datetime': '2013-01-01T00:20:00+02:00', 'channels': [
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'Rain', 'alias': None, 'value': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'WSmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 8.8, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'WDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 42.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'WS', 'alias': None, 'value': 5.6, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 5, 'name': 'WD', 'alias': None, 'value': 55.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 6, 'name': 'STDwd', 'alias': None, 'value': 12.8, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 7, 'name': 'RH', 'alias': None, 'value': 55.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 8, 'name': 'TD', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 10, 'name': 'TDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 11, 'name': 'TDmin', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 13, 'name': 'WS1mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 6.8, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 14, 'name': 'Ws10mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 6.3, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 15, 'name': 'Time', 'alias': None, 'value': 12.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None}]},
 {'datetime': '2013-01-01T00:30:00+02:00', 'channels': [
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'Rain', 'alias': None, 'value': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'WSmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 10.4, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'WDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 60.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'WS', 'alias': None, 'value': 5.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 5, 'name': 'WD', 'alias': None, 'value': 54.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 6, 'name': 'STDwd', 'alias': None, 'value': 11.9, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 7, 'name': 'RH', 'alias': None, 'value': 55.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 8, 'name': 'TD', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.4, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 10, 'name': 'TDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 11, 'name': 'TDmin', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.3, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 13, 'name': 'WS1mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 7.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 14, 'name': 'Ws10mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 5.6, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 15, 'name': 'Time', 'alias': None, 'value': 21.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None}]},
 {'datetime': '2013-01-01T00:40:00+02:00', 'channels': [
     {'id': 1, 'name': 'Rain', 'alias': None, 'value': 0.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 2, 'name': 'WSmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 9.5, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 3, 'name': 'WDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 61.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 4, 'name': 'WS', 'alias': None, 'value': 5.7, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 5, 'name': 'WD', 'alias': None, 'value': 52.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 6, 'name': 'STDwd', 'alias': None, 'value': 11.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 7, 'name': 'RH', 'alias': None, 'value': 55.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 8, 'name': 'TD', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.2, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 10, 'name': 'TDmax', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.3, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 11, 'name': 'TDmin', 'alias': None, 'value': 13.2, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 13, 'name': 'WS1mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 7.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 14, 'name': 'Ws10mm', 'alias': None, 'value': 5.7, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None},
     {'id': 15, 'name': 'Time', 'alias': None, 'value': 40.0, 'status': 1, 'valid': True, 'description': None}]}]
```

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open(r"Documents\dat.json") as data_file:
    js_dict = json.load(data_file)
columns =list(json_normalize(js_dict["data"][0]["channels"]) 
   ["name"])
df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in js_dict["data"]:
    val = json_normalize(row,record_path="channels").transpose().iloc[6]
    new_val = pd.DataFrame(val).transpose().reset_index()
    df = df.append(new_val)

print(df)
```

***EDIT***

I used another more basic script using less pandas functions and shortened the time considerably, I am wondering why the pandas functions are so slow

```
from glob import glob
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import time
import cProfile


def timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print('{:s} function took {:.3f} ms'.format(f.__name__, (time2- 
       time1)*1000.0))
        return ret
    return wrap


@timing
def convert_json_panda_I(js_dict):
    columns =list(json_normalize(js_dict[0]["channels"])["name"])
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for row in js_dict:
        val = json_normalize(row,record_path="channels").transpose().iloc[6]
        new_val = pd.DataFrame(val).transpose().reset_index()
        df = df.append(new_val)
    return df


def decode_dict(dat):
    row = []
    for k, v in dat.items():
        if k in 'datetime':
            date = v
            row.append(date)
        elif k in 'channels':
            for chanell in v:
                row.append(chanell["value"])
    return row


@timing
def convert_json_panda_II(json_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame([decode_dict(line) for line in json_dict])
    return df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(r"C:\cygwin64\bin\zefat_bp.json") as data_file:
        js_dict = json.load(data_file)
    print("first version profile")
    first_version = convert_json_panda_I(js_dict["data"])
    print("second version profile")
    second_version = cProfile.run('convert_json_panda_II(js_dict["data"])')
    print(type(second_version))
    print(second_version.head())
```

The difference in timing is very big:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.4445.76)

convert_json_panda_I function took 2298914.500 ms

convert_json_panda_II function took 1389.219 ms
```

why is using pandas functions so slow?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `df.append(new_val)` create a full new Pandas dataframe for each row (it *copy* the previous one and add just a new row). Thus, with `1,000,000` rows, the first version will generate 1,000,000 dataframes with an average of 500,000 rows each. The second approach generate only one big dataframe directly. The the point is: do not use `append` of Pandas, **use `concat`**. Here is an example:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
with open(r"Documents\dat.json") as data_file:
    js_dict = json.load(data_file)
columns =list(json_normalize(js_dict["data"][0]["channels"]) 
   ["name"])

rows = []
for row in js_dict["data"]:
    val = json_normalize(row,record_path="channels").transpose().iloc[6]
    rows.append(pd.DataFrame(val).transpose().reset_index())
df = pd.concat(rows)

print(df)
```