# I have some code that take under 2 seconds to run 100 iterations, under 8 seconds to run 1000, and over 11 minutes to run 10,000

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, multiprocessing

I'm a hobbyist programmer, and this is just a little project I set for myself. I know I very likely have something in this code that is inefficient enough to not matter for small loops but is compounding when I scale it up. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```py
def RndSelection(ProjMatrix):
    
    
    percentiles = [0,10,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,75,80,90,99]
    results = []
    
    
    for row in ProjMatrix.itertuples():
        
        x = npr.randint(1,100)
        
        for p in range(3,16):
            
            if  p < 15:
                a = percentiles[p-3]
                b = percentiles[p-2]
                
                if x in range (a,b):
                
                                   
                    factor = (b-x)/(b-a)
                    r = round((row[p]*factor)+((row[p+1])*(1-factor)),2)
                    break
            else:
                r = row[p]

        results.append(r)
        
    thisrun = pd.DataFrame(results)
    
        
    return(thisrun)
                    

def main():

    ts = datetime.datetime.now()
    print ('Run Started: ', ts)    

    Matrix = SetMatrix()
    Outcome = Matrix['player_id']

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(RndSelection,Matrix) for _ in range(10000)]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            thisrun = f.result()
            Outcome = pd.concat([Outcome,thisrun],axis=1)




    print(Outcome)

    ts = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('Run Completed: ', ts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not a [mre]. IndentationError's. Missing functiuons.

Comment: Sorry, I tried for several minutes to get it to indent properly in the code example paste. The missing function is reading in csv data and putting into a table. Since its dependant upon source data I can't easily replicate here, and only being called once outside of the loop I didn't think it relevant. 

If I was mistaken I can write up a quick random number generator to mimic the data.

Comment: There are still missing functions like `SetMatrix`. The problem comes from concat which causes a quadratic runtime. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093377/nested-json-to-pandas-very-slow/67060952#67060952).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer, as Jérôme pointed out, was the iteration of the concat.

Moving the output to a list of lists and then concat just once improved the runtime of 10,000 interactions to 8 seconds and 100,000 iterations to 2 mins, 34 seconds.

```py
def RndSelection(ProjMatrix):
    
    
    percentiles = [0,10,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,75,80,90,99]
    results = []
    r = ""
    
    for row in ProjMatrix.itertuples():
        
        x = npr.randint(1,100)
        
        
        for p in range(3,16):
            
            if  p < 15:
                a = percentiles[p-3]
                b = percentiles[p-2]
                
                if x in range (a,b):
                
                                   
                    factor = (b-x)/(b-a)
                    r = round((row[p]*factor)+((row[p+1])*(1-factor)),2)
                    break
            else:
                r = row[p]

        results.append(r)
        

    
        
    return results
                    




def main():

    ts = datetime.datetime.now()
    print ('Run Started: ', ts)    

    Matrix = SetMatrix()
    runs = 100000
    s = 0
    Outcome = pd.DataFrame(Matrix['player_id'])
    
    thisrun = np.empty((runs,0)).tolist()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(RndSelection,Matrix) for _ in range(runs)]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):

            thisrun[s]=f.result()
            s += 1

    allruns = pd.DataFrame(thisrun).transpose()
    Outcome = pd.concat([Outcome,allruns],axis=1)




    ts = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('Run Completed: ', ts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```